# How to print path of the textfile that we just write in another directory and print string in every file in Python

Tags: python

How to print path that we just print to the textfile. Example:

I have textfile.txt path on D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt. Have string like this

```
string1
i have pen
i have book
string2
i have ruler
i have bag
author : stevanus
```

then split the textfile.txt to two files that print the path on every textfile. Print the path above it and print author below it in every file. And in another path on D:/Workspace/savedfile. Example

in the textfile1.txt

```
path : D:/Workspace/savedfile/textfile1.txt <-- print the path but textfile1.txt
string1
i have pen
i have book
author : stevanus <-- print the author
```

in the textfile2.txt

```
path : D:/Workspace/savedfile/textfile2.txt  <-- print the path but textfile2.txt
string2
i have ruler
i have bag
author : stevanus <-- print the author again
```

this is the code so far

```
linenum = 1
filename = ''

with open('D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    for line in (inf):
        if 'string'in line:
            filename = 'D:/Workspace/savedfile/textfile{}.txt'.format(linenum)
            open(filename,'w')
            linenum+=1

        with open(filename, 'a') as outf:
            outf.write(line)
```

in short how to print the path of the new file stored and print string from the original file to the all new file. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You first have to get the last line from your source file. Otherwise you won't be able to write this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think itertools.chain is a better way to split file.

After for loop, the variable "line" becomes "author : stevanus" and then you can add it to each file except the last one.

```
from itertools import chain
filename = 'D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt'
with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
    header = next(inf)
    for index, line in enumerate(inf,start=1):
        with open('D:/Workspace/Python/textfile{}.txt'.format(index) ,'w') as outf:
            outf.write('Path : %s\n' %outf.name)
            outf.write(header)
            for line in chain([line], inf):
                if 'string' in line:
                    header = line
                    break
                outf.write(line)

    for idx in range(1, index):
        filename = 'textfile{}.txt'.format(idx)
        with open(filename, 'a') as outf:
            outf.write(line)
```

Comment: i wanna ask. how to get another 2 line of string from bottom. for example before author string have date string. i need both of string printed.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply :

- open a new file each time you find `string` in a line
- keep all opened files in a list
- when you find `author` in a line, add this line to all opened files and close them

It could look like :

```
linenum = 1
files = []
with open('D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    for line in (inf):
        if 'string'in line:
            filename = 'D:/Workspace/Python/textfile{}.txt'.format(linenum)
            fd = open(filename,'w')
            linenum+=1
            files.append(fd)
        elif 'author' in line:
            for fd in files:
                fd.write(line)
                fd.close()
            break
        fd.write(line)
```

You should add some error handling in case of badly formatted file, but it works for a correct input file.